# Rename file attachment in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, rename, attachment, parameters

I would like to rename requested file by GET param.

So when I call:
(...)media/models/admin_test/1/image?filename=blabla.png

It should set name of requested file to "blabla.png"

I tried this one:

```
SetEnvIf Query_String "\?filename=(.+)$" FILENAME=$1
Header set Content-Type application/octet-stream
Header set Content-Disposition "attachment; filename=%{FILENAME}e"
UnsetEnv FILENAME
```

But I get (null) as name.
Any suggestions?

Comment: [Does `SetEnvIf` support **Query_String**?](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_setenvif.html#setenvif)

Comment: You are right. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_setenvif.html it doesn't support Query_String. I found it somewhere and used it, without checking. But do you have any other idea to get required result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try mod_rewrite rules in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)filename=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [E=FILENAME:%1]

Header set Content-Type application/octet-stream
Header set Content-Disposition "attachment; filename=%{FILENAME}e"
```

Comment: Brilliant. Work like a charm.